# How to compute this sum over numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

When I was doing some task of analytic number theory I was stuck on computing  this sum
$$S:=\frac{1}{L} \sum_{q \in \mathcal{Q}} \phi(q) \overline{a}^{\frac{1}{2}},$$
where  $\overline{a}$ is the inverse of $a$ modulo $q>0,$  $\mathcal{Q}$ is a nonempty set of numbers defined by 
$$\mathcal{Q}=\left\{q \in [Q,2Q]; \ \gcd(a,q)=1\right\}, \quad Q\geq 1$$ and 
$$L=\sum_{q \in \mathcal{Q}} \phi(q),$$ $\phi$ is the Euler function.
 Can someone help me in doing this task? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it's not clear what range for $\bar{a}$ you are expecting. If we just assume that it is in the range of $(0,q)$, I think you can simply consider a function $H: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $H(n) = n^{1/2}$ for integers in the range $[0,2Q]$ and 0 elsewhere. Then $\bar{a}^{1/2}$ mod $q$ is merely $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}} H\left(\frac{ax-1}{q}\right)$, up to some small error. You can clearly smooth this function as well.

Comment: Just to make sure: you really want the *real, positive* square root of $a\in(0,q)$, not the mod $q$ version of that?

Comment: @FanZheng, I want the square root  of the inverse of a fixed integer $a$ modulo $q.$

Comment: @KhadijaMbarki Then how do you make sure that $a$ is a quadratic residue mod $q$?

Comment: @KhadijaMbarki Also, you are summing over residue classes in different moduli, which doesn't make much sense, unless you specify a representative of that residue class.